# скрыть элемент шапки

Tags: javascript, html

есть в шапке такие элементы:

```
            <a href="authorization.html">Вход</a>
            <a href="registration.html">Регистрация</a>
            <a class='is_logged' href="#" onclick="onlineShopLogout()">Выход</a>
```

Необходимо для залогиненных пользователей отображать только "Выход",а для анлог- Вход и регистрацию

Есть функция которая чекает:

```
function onlineShopAuth(){
    IO.Auth.check({
        success: function(object){
            $(".is_un_logged").hide();
            $(".is_logged").show();
        }, fail: function(){
            $(".is_logged").hide();
            $(".is_un_logged").show();
        }
    });
}




    function onlineShopLogout(){
         IO.Auth.logout({success: function(){
        $(".is_un_logged").show();
        $(".is_logged").hide();             

    }});
}
```

Кнопки должны скрываться примерно таким методом:

```
             <a class='is_un_logged' href="authorization.html">Вход</a>
             <a class='is_un_logged' href="registration.html">Регистрация</a>
             <a class='is_logged' href="#" onclick="onlineShopLogout()">Выход</a>
```

Они не скрываются,что я делаю не так?
Как я должен вызвать функцию чтобы ссылки скрывались?

Comment: Установите классы "is_un_logged" по умолчанию для тегов "a", и сделайте вызов функции onlineShopAuth при загрузке страницы.

Comment: вызываю,ничего не происходит

Comment: Возможно, не вызываются колбеки `success` и `fail`. Поставьте внутрь этих колбеков `console.log`, для просмотра, работают ли они.